# Does this method of finding the range of rational functions always work?

Tags: proof-verification, rational-functions

Consider the irreducible rational function in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

> $$y=\frac{A(x)}{B(x)}$$
>
> where at least one term is quadratic and the other term has degree either 0, 1 or 2.

The classic way of finding the range of these rational functions is to re-arrange the equation as a quadratic in $x$, and then let the discriminant be greater than or equal to zero. Upon solving this inequality for $y$, one acquires the range of this rational function.

> My question is, does this method **always** work? Is there a counter-example floating out there?

Comment: What do you mean by "obscure"? What if $A(x)=B(x)=x^2$?

Comment: Do you want an answer just for $\deg A = \deg B = 2$?

Comment: I have clarified my question further, cheers.

Comment: it's a good discussion

Comment: Yes it does work always why do you think it doesn't can you give an example?